# How to find non-trivial solution to homogeneous linear equations by Mathematica using code (Input form)?

Tags: linear-algebra, fluid-dynamics

I have many homogeneous equations to which I am interested to find the non-trivial solution using Mathematica, But I am totally new to Mathematica, so I do no know, how to find the non-trivial solution to them by Mathematica. The equations are:

$\alpha_1+2\alpha_2-2\alpha_3=3\alpha_2-\alpha_3=\alpha_2-\alpha_3=-\alpha_6=-\alpha_7;$

$\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3-\alpha_6=2\alpha_2-\alpha_6=2\alpha_2-\alpha_6-\alpha_7=2\alpha_2-2\alpha_6$

$\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3-\alpha_7=2\alpha_2-\alpha_7=2\alpha_2-\alpha_6$

Comment: Edit your question to include the copy and paste-able code (`InputForm`) for your equations and the code for what you have tried.

Comment: You could write out the matrix for this system of equations and then ask for the `NullSpace`.

Comment: This is not copy and paste-able code. Convert your Mathematica cell to `InputForm` (Menu command), then copy and paste into MSE.